# Send custom Facebook notification from iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, ipad

I am trying to send a Facebook notification via iOS, i've looked in Facebook's Docs section, here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/notifications

But it didn't work.
At first i get reponse messages from Facebook saying it has to be a canvas so that notifications work,
Then, when I added the canvas plateform in my Facebook Back Office, I keep getting this Exception error :

```
"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.";
```

Anyone manage to make this work ?
What did I miss ?

Comment: Can you maybe post your code so we can see whats going on.

Comment: I followed the instructions in this link, and it seems to work ! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1

Comment: so...do you want to send notifications, or do you want to send app requests?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

It is a lot more detailed and explains how to use App Notifications. You need an App Token, which is just a combination of App ID and App Secret: APPID|APPSECRET (separated with a pipe)

Comment: That's what I thought, but I tried that, and it doesn't seem to work !

Comment: what exactly did you try? you really need to include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: It explicitly says on the page @luschn mentioned, _“Currently, only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications. Notifications are only surfaced on the desktop version of Facebook.com.”_

Comment: As I said above, I followed the instructions in this link: developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1

Comment: as i asked you above: do you want to send notifications or app requests? because in your question you linked to the notifications...